# how to draw path in an indoor map on BIT I have

Tags: android, path

I am creating a very simple indoor map app  , i need to draw a path from room to another room on top of an image of a building layout I have.
I am very new to programming , I programming on anroid using Java language.

Comment: What is your question ? You may need to look a few basic Java or android tutorials.

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look into both:

1. Path finding (such as A*) including translating the map into a navigatable object and
2. LWJGL (aka OpenGL) or other drawing library